# What's the best way to shrink a calendar to only contain the necessary calendar objects depending on a start and end date

Tags: c#, .net, icalendar, ical-dotnet

Using iCal.Net.

What I'm trying to achieve, is to shrink a calendar to send it over the internet, so I don't have to send the whole calendar, which would be wasteful (considering it can get big) if I'm asked what happens in a single day.

We should only send what occurs in the given period.

```
Calendar.GetOccurrences(IDateTime startTime, IDateTime endTime)
```

Seems to be a good start, I'm not sure how to get the actual CalendarObject then, nor if it's the good approach.

Comment: Show us what have you already tried.

Comment: @dymanoid I've not tried anything yet, mostly reading the library's source code, so far I've not really found my solution and was wondering if someone with a better knowledge would know an obvious solution.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a use case I haven't encountered before, but it shouldn't be too difficult. I think I'd do something like this:

```
var relevantEvents = bigCalendar.GetOccurrences(start, end)
    .Select(o => o.Source)  // The parent IRecurrable
    .Cast<Event>()          // Which is an Event/CalendarEvent
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();

var smallerCalendar = new Calendar();

// I should add an extension method to UniqueComponentList for AddRange()
foreach (var relevantEvent in relevantEvents)
{
    smallerCalendar.Events.Add(relevantEvent);
}
```

Comment: I added this example to the ical.net wiki: https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net/wiki/Working-with-collections-of-calendar-events#extract-a-range-of-calendar-events-from-a-calendar

Comment: Thank you very much @rianjs! I'll try this and let you know.